# How to access a dynamically allocated matrix in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, memory-management, matrix

I have created a dynamic matrix of class objects but i have made a big mess with handling the returned pointers.

My intention is to create a matrix of class Point( Int x,Int y) and later to use it in different ways in the program.
Everything is working but i can't figure out the returned pointers game between the functions.

```
class Point
{
   private:
     int x; 
     int y;
   public:
     Point(int x,int y);
     void SetPoint(int x,int y);

};
```

In a second class I use a Point object as class member.

Init_Pallet() is used to Initialize the Matrix.

```
class Warehouse
{
   private:
       Robot r1,r2;
       Point *Pallet_Matrix;

   public:
       Point* Init_Pallet();
};
```

This is the Init function

```
Point* Warehouse::Init_Pallet()
{

    int rows =10,cols =10;
    Point** Pallet_Matrix = new Point*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        Pallet_Matrix[i] = new Point[cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)     //Pallet matrix Init, x point for robots amount in position and y for box amount
            Pallet_Matrix[i][j].SetPoint(0,0);
    return *Pallet_Matrix;
}
```

The Init function is called by WareHouse C'Tor (ignore the other vars)

```
Warehouse::Warehouse(Robot p_r1,Robot p_r2): r1(p_r1),r2(p_r2)
{
    this->r1=p_r1;
    this->r2=p_r2;
    Point *p =Init_Pallet();
    this->Pallet_Matrix=p;
}
```

My question is: How do I return the address to the beginning of the matrix from the Init function to the C'Tor who called it?
And second question: how do i access the matrix different locations in the format of Matrix[i][j] after returning the matrix adress to the C'Tor.

Thank you in advance for all the help and your time.

Comment: *"big mess with handling the returned pointers"* - you should avoid pointers at first place.

Comment: I would appreciate any help avoiding them. in this case it's kind of a problem not to use them

Comment: Why make `pallet_matrix` private and then return a pointer to it? i.e.making it not private any more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just have `Init_Pallet` return a `Point**` and then do `return Pallet_Matrix;`. Currently you're copying one of the `Point*`s that you allocated out of the function, so the copy is no longer part of a contiguous array that you can index.

Don't forget to `delete[]` the dynamically arrays in your destructor.

However, you should much prefer to use the standard library containers like `std::array` or `std::vector`. Then you don't need to worry about the dynamic allocation yourself and no pointers to get in a mess with.

If I were doing it, I would just have:

```
class Warehouse
{
   public:
       Warehouse() : Pallet_Matrix() { }
   private:
       Robot r1,r2;
       std::array<std::array<Point, 10>, 10> Pallet_Matrix;
};
```

And that's it. No `init` needed. No dynamic allocation. No assigning 0 to every element (if you give `Point` a default constructor that zero-initialises). Done.

Comment: +1 If the `Pallet_Matrix` is really meant to be of a fixed size, this would be a good way to go.

Comment: You might want to explain why `Warehouse() : Pallet_Matrix() {}` works, when `Point` doesn't have a default constructor.  And why it wouldn't do the right thing if the default constructor of `Point` were the equivalent of `Point( 1, 1 )`.

Answer (score 2):

*How do I return the address to the beginning of the matrix from the Init function to the C'Tor?*

In case you would really need just an address of first element, pretty straightforward would be:

```
return &Pallet_Matrix[0][0];
```

*how do i access the matrix different locations in the format of Matrix[i][j] after returning the matrix address*

`Init_Pallet` is a member function, which could simply work with the `Pallet_Matrix` member directly. Otherwise, the `Init_Pallet` function could actually return `Point**`, which should however make you feel that something's wrong with this code.

---

Better<sup>[1]</sup> solution would be:

1. Define the default constructor for `Point`:

   ```
   class Point
   {
      public:
        Point() : x(0), y(0){}
        ...
   ```
2. Use `std::vector`s instead of dynamically allocated arrays:

   ```
   class Warehouse
   {
      private:
          std::vector< std::vector<Point> > Pallet_Matrix;
   ```

   and instead of:

   ```
   Point *p =Init_Pallet();
   this->Pallet_Matrix=p;
   ```

   you would simply use `std::vector`'s constructor:

   ```
   int rows = 10, cols = 10;
   Pallet_Matrix = std::vector< std::vector<Point> >(rows, cols);
   ```

*<sup>[1] Better = **You don't want to handle the memory management on your own.**</sup>*

Comment: Lets say i i created a Warehouse object by calling the C'Tor.
How can i access the Matrix which is a variable of this object?
thanks

Comment: @YushN: You could make `Pallet_Matrix` `public` and do for example: `Warehouse* w = new Warehouse(...); w->Pallet_Matrix[0][0] = 7;`. Depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the returned type of `Init_Pallet()` is wrong — its a row, not a matrix. And in the last line of `Warehouse::Init_Pallet()` you dereference the proper pointer to matrix obtaining the pointer to the first row of the matrix.

You need to write `Point **Pallet_Matrix;` in `Warehouse`, use `Point** Warehouse::Init_Pallet()` definition of `Init_pallet()`, and `return Pallet_Matrix` in the last line of `Init_Pallet()`.

The notation `Point *row` means the `row` is "the array of points" or "the pointer to the beginning of the array of points". The notation `Point **matrix` means the `matrix` is "the array of pointers to the beginnings of the arrays of points" or "the pointer to the beginning of such an array".

Answer (score 0):

First: are the dimensions really constant, or is this just an
artifact of your having simplified the code for posting?  If
they are really constant, there's no need for dynamic
allocation: you can just write:

```
Point palletMatrix[10][10];
```

and be done with it.  (If you have C++11, it's even better; you
can use `std::array`, and `palletMatrix` will have full object
semantics.)

If you do need dynamic indexes, the *only* reasonable way of
doing this is to write a simple matrix class, and use it:

```
class Matrix
{
    int m_rows;
    int m_columns;
    std::vector<Point> m_data;
public:
    Matrix( int rows, int columns )
        : m_rows( rows )
        , m_columns( columns )
        , m_data( rows * columns, Point( 0, 0 ) )
    {
    }
    Point& operator()( int i, int j )
    {
        return m_data[ i * m_columns + j ];
    }
    //  ...
};
```

Trying to maintain a table of pointers to tables is not a good
solution: it's overly complex, it requires special handling to
ensure that each row has the same number of columns, and it
generally has poor performance (on modern machines, at least,
where locality is important and multiplication is cheap).

Note too that the actual data is in an `std::vector`.  There are
practically no cases where a `new[]` is a good solution; if you
didn't have `std::vector` (and there was such a time), you'd
start by implementing it, or something similar.  (And
`std::vector` does not use `new[]` either.)

EDIT:

One other thing: if you're putting `Point` in a matrix, you might
want to give it a default constructor; this often makes the code
simpler.